# How to Know Current Install Location

Tags: android, adb

I read in internet that using the below code will set the install location to sdcard

```
adb shell pm set-install-location 2
```

But how to know the current setting of the install location?

In Vb.net or VBA we use (Question Mark) ?adb shell pm set-install-location to get the current setting.

Is it same in android or I needed something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for this command: `adb shell pm get-install-location`

- 0 [auto]: Let system decide the best location
- 1 [internal]: Install on internal device storage
- 2 [external]: Install on external media

[source](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html)

Comment: and what about Flyme OS? cause I've been tryed change install location, and get exception `Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Package android does not belong to 2000`

Comment: Try running `adb root` first

Answer (score 1):

By using adb shell pm getInstallLocation you can get the install location